# Ajuda para obter valores em struct(Arduino,C++)

Tags: c++, arduino

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com esp32(similar a arduino) que obtenha data e hora de um servidor NTP. Uso a seguinte função para mostrar esses valores:

```cpp
void printLocalTime()
{
  struct tm timeinfo;
  if(!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)){
    Serial.println("Falha ao obter hora");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println(&timeinfo, "%A, %B, %d %Y %H:%M:%S");
}
```

Consigo obter(exibir) os valores normalmente, porém eu quero armazená-los em uma variável, mas não sei como acessá-los dentro da struct timeinfo, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Utilize timeinfo(ponto) e o nome do valor da struct que deseja acessar, os dados dessa struct estão no link:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/

Exemplo:
timeinfo.tm_sec

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para acessar membros de uma `struct` basta usar a sintaxe `variavel.membro`. No caso da `struct tm`, [os membros são](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/):

```
tm_sec   int    seconds after the minute   0-61*
tm_min   int    minutes after the hour     0-59
tm_hour  int    hours since midnight       0-23
tm_mday  int    day of the month           1-31
tm_mon   int    months since January       0-11
tm_year  int    years since 1900
tm_wday  int    days since Sunday          0-6
tm_yday  int    days since January 1       0-365
tm_isdst int    Daylight Saving Time flag
```

Então a chamada do `Serial.print*()` poderia ficar da seguinte maneira:

```cpp
Serial.printf("%d/%02d/%04d %d:%02d:%02d",
    timeinfo.tm_year + 1900, timeinfo.tm_mon + 1, timeinfo.tm_mday,
    timeinfo.tm_hour, timeinfo.tm_min, timeinfo.tm_sec);
```